# Can I select a whole week with ngbDatepicker?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ng-bootstrap

I've made a datepicker in Angular 8 using the ngbDatepicker from the ng-bootstrap library.

I want to select a whole week by clicking on the weekdays on the left. I know I can select a date and get the week from that but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Is this possible in some way?

My Template:

```
<div id="datepicker-container">
    <p>Pick a date:</p>
    <!-- Datepicker made using ng bootstrap library
    https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview -->
    <ngb-datepicker
        (select)="onDateSelection($event)" 
        [showWeekNumbers]="true"
        [outsideDays]="outsideDays"
        [maxDate]="maxDate">
    </ngb-datepicker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can "play" using a day-template. Based on Day template of range selection you can use the styles

```
  .custom-day {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0.185rem 0.25rem;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 2rem;
      width: 2rem;
    }
  .custom-day.range{
      background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
      color: white;
    }
```

And the functions

```
  isInside(date: NgbDate) {
    return date.after(this.fromDate) && date.before(this.toDate);
  }

  isRange(date: NgbDate) {
    return date.equals(this.fromDate) || date.equals(this.toDate) || this.isInside(date);
  }
```

The day template like:

```
<ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
  <span class="custom-day"
        [class.focused]="focused"
        [class.range]="isRange(date)"
        >
    {{ date.day }}
  </span>
</ng-template>
```

So, the only thing that you need is, when change select, calculate fromDate and toDate

```
  onDateSelection(date:NgbDate)
  {
    let fromDate=new Date(date.year+'-'+date.month+'-'+date.day)
    let time=fromDate.getDay()?fromDate.getDay()-1:6
    fromDate=new Date(fromDate.getTime()-time*24*60*60*1000)
    this.fromDate=new NgbDate(fromDate.getFullYear(),fromDate.getMonth()+1,fromDate.getDate());
    const toDate=new Date(fromDate.getTime()+6*24*60*60*1000)
    this.toDate=new NgbDate(toDate.getFullYear(),toDate.getMonth()+1,toDate.getDate())
  }
```

Well, we need other things that is return the week and year when we has the toDate. To this we use this two auxiliar functions

```
  calculateWeek(date:any)
  {
    const time = date.getTime()+4*24*60*60*1000;
    const firstDay=new Date(date.getFullYear()+'-1-1')
    return Math.floor(Math.round((time - firstDay.getTime()) / 86400000) / 7) + 1;
  }
  calculateDate(week:number,year:number)
  {
    const firstDay=new Date(year+'-1-4')
    const date=new Date(firstDay.getTime()+(week-1)*7*24*60*60*1000)
    const selectDate=new NgbDate(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+1,date.getDate())
    this.onDateSelection(selectDate)

  }
```

We can enclosed all in a custom form control implements our component from ControlValueAccessor, and after calculate the toDate and fromDate call to onChange

see the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrvbmv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fweek-picker%2Fweek-picker.component.ts)